# Why I am getting Timeout Error in my live site

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am facing a problem with my live site. The Issue is a **SQLTimeout** error.

I have followed the below scenario to solve the issue. But I can't do it .

Steps taken:

1. Increased the `SqlCommand` Timeout = 0 and 240
2. Increased the `SqlCommand` Connection Timeout = 0
3. I have applied raw SQL in code to fetch the data from SQL Server

Kindly share with me if you have any suggestions about this issue.

Thanks

Comment: We can help, if you provide relevant code.

Comment: show your exact error and stack trace

Comment: Sadly this translates into "Teach me sql basics" which is toooooo broad. Except in very rare circumstancees ALL your changes did NOTHING - except make the problem worse. Like trying to fill up a gas tank when the gas is running down because ofa a hole. If you have EXTREMELY slow SQL, how many hours you want sql statements to wait before a timeout? Start doing basics. Indices, reading the documentation, likely helps.

Comment: i think you have getting some data from multiple table . In your second request hit the existing accessed table .

Comment: please use isolation concept to avoid the time out error .

Comment: [Troubleshooting timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/troubleshoot-query-timeouts)

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to address your issue with so little info you provided.

Generally I would recommend to execute your query in SQL Server Management Studio and see what happens.

It could be either really long query or locking issue in database.
Also be aware, if you host you site on IIS, that apart from SQL Server timeout, the IIS request timeout would apply.

Answer (score 0):

Example :

Table 1,
Table 2 ,
Table 3

Issue Scenario:
**You have  request to get those three table values .But the second request used to store some value in any one table at the same time existing request is not completed  .**

you will get the timeout error here , because existing request is not completed ,

**Solutions :**
Please use isolation concept to avoid this error while writing and read and updated time

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of issues will give on the below scenarios

1.Multiple request occurred on the same table like Searching. Updating, searching Deleting (In the sql server)
2.Searching and fetched the bulk data without using with(nolock) in that query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).